# fitspeed2 fit speed.m

Tags: matlab

I have a program which I can't figure its problem

```
Error in ==> fitspeed2 at 7
sysf=gain/dcgain(sys)*sys;[Fitted_Curve, t]=lsim(sysf, y, Input);
```

program

```
function sse=fitspeed2(params,Input,Actual_Output) 
b=params(1);
c=params(2);
global y gain
sys=tf(1, conv([1 b c], [1 3.35]));
if (length(t) ~= length(Input))
    Fitted_Curve=Fitted_Curve(1:round(length(t)/length(Input)):end,:);
end
Error_Vector=Fitted_Curve - Actual_Output;
sse=sum(Error_Vector.^2);
```

Comment: Did you put the wrong function definition into your question? The line `sysf=gain/dcgain(sys)*sys;[Fitted_Curve, t]=lsim(sysf, y, Input);` referenced in the error message doesn't appear anywhere in it. You'll also need to tell us what these globals are, and give an example of using the function.